# Improper integral of certain kind

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

Let $\phi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $\phi(x)\to 0$ as $x\to +\infty$, and let $\psi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $\int_I \psi(x)dx$ is $\textit{uniformly}$ bounded over all compact intervals $I$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

$\textbf{My Question}$ : Can we say that the improper integral $\int_0^{+\infty} \phi(x)\psi(x)dx$ is convergent ?

If the answer is yes then we can say that a lot many improper integral is convergent.

I have this feeling that the answer is yes but I don't know how to prove this rigorously. I would be grateful for any kind of help.

Comment: This is false (see @user6247850 's answer below) but becomes [true if $\phi$ is moreover (non-strictly) decreasing](https://fr.wikiversity.org/wiki/Int%C3%A9gration_de_Riemann/Int%C3%A9grales_g%C3%A9n%C3%A9ralis%C3%A9es#R%C3%A8gle_d'Abel) (even without continuity assumptions).

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not true.  Let $\psi(x) = \sin(x)$ and $\phi(x) = \sin(x)/x$.  The periodicity of $\sin(x)$ ensures that $|\int_I\psi(x)dx| \le 2$ for all compact intervals $I$.  However, \begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty \psi(x)\phi(x)dx &= \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x)^2}{x}dx \\
&\ge \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi} \frac{\sin(x)^2}{x}dx \\
&\ge \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi} \frac{\sin(x)^2}{(n+1)\pi}dx \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2(n+1)} \\
&= \infty.\end{align*}